Highlight JS code inside XML element or inside CDATA in VS code
I want to have JS syntax highlighting inside certain XML elements. E.g.
 <Module Name="Main">
<![CDATA[
   var obj = {};
   obj.car = { Name: 'car', HP: 135};
   obj.drive = function(car){...}
]]></Module>

This currently shows up as

Is there any extension that enables highlighting of the JS inside the element or do i have to do something custom?
I tried all kinds of XML extensions, none seem to have that integrated.

Made a small project, i will probably change it up a little bit but at its core it has JS syntax highlighting inside CDATA: https://github.com/Hrachkata/RCM-highlighter


Please use code insert instead of picture

How does copy&pasted code showcase syntax highlighting?

You could try the extended-embedded-languages extension
If not. Create a feature request to https://github.com/ruschaaf/extended-embedded-languages/issues

This extension seems awesome, but do you perhaps have an XML example. I tried different things but their documentation and github examples barely cover XML.
